# assigning app to domain user in kiosk mode by powershell windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, mode, kiosk

I am trying to assign an app to user in kiosk mode on windows 10. I use script in powershell:

```
 Set-AssignedAccess -AppName ICI-app -UserName y3022
```

y3022 is a name of domain user
ICI-app is an application

```
Set-AssignedAccess -AppName ICI-app -UserName domainName\y3022
```

doesn't work too

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C54aL.png)

with local user it works. How can I set it to domain user?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN explicitly states that the -UserName and -UserSID parameters cannot be domain accounts or local administrator accounts:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/assignedaccess/set-assignedaccess?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 0):

I have found the sollution. First I assigned access for app for local account. It made key in regedit. I found this key and I changed SID (yellow selected on screen) on domain user's key. It works well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR20u.png)